# Flutter BLOC: when receiving data synchronously over http, the widget content is not updated

Tags: flutter, http, bloc

Good afternoon!
The problem is the following: when receiving data synchronously over http, the widget content is not updated.

BLOC code:

```
class NotifyBloc extends Bloc<NotifyEvent, NotifyState> {
  Map result={};
  NotifyBloc() : super(NotifyState().init()) {
    on<InitEvent>(_init);
    on<UpdateList>((event, emit)  {
      print("Update list..");
      NotifyState res=NotifyState();
      res.NotifyList=globals.NotifyList;
      emit(res);
    });
    on<LoadNotify>((event, emit)  {
      NotifyState res=NotifyState();
      TRequests req=new TRequests();
      req.request("GetListPushMessages", jsonEncode({
        "hash": globals.UserInfo["md5hash"],
        "count": 50,
      }), (answer){
        print("Enter: $answer");
        res.NotifyList=answer;
        globals.NotifyList=answer;
        NotifyBloc().add(UpdateList());
      }, (error){
      });
      emit(res);
    });
}
```

Widget on start:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();   
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => BlocProvider.of<NotifyBloc>(context).add(LoadNotify()));
  }
```

By design, when opening the page, before rendering, the widget should initiate
data loading via http, and after receiving the data, it should draw them.

It is noteworthy that with an asynchronous request, everything works out correctly, but I need synchronous loading, because
the loading time can be significant.

Working, but not the correct code:

```
on<LoadNotify>((event, emit)  async {
  NotifyState res=NotifyState();
  TRequests req=new TRequests();
  http.Response response;
  response=await req.asyncRequest("GetListPushMessages", jsonEncode({
    "hash": globals.UserInfo["md5hash"],
    "count": 50,
  }));
  sleep(Duration(seconds:10));
    Map<String, dynamic> answer = jsonDecode(response.body);
      res.NotifyList = answer["result"];
  emit(res);      
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because of `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => BlocProvider.of<NotifyBloc>(context).add(LoadNotify()));` you basically adding this event, after you draw whole page, and also because you adding another event `UpdateList()`, and after that you emiting state from `LoadNotify()` and they are propably woriking not in order you wanted. Instead you can do something like this

```
// Widget
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();BlocProvider.of<NotifyBloc>(context).add(LoadNotify());
}
...
if (state is NotifyLoading) {
  return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
}


// NotifyState
class NotifyLoading extends NotifyState {}
class NotifyLoaded extends NotifyState {
  final Response /* <- your response type*/ response;
  const NotifyLoaded({required this.response});
}

// NotifyBloc
on<LoadNotify>((event, emit)  {
  emit(NotifyLoading()); // handle this loading in Widget
  TRequests req=new TRequests();
  req.request("GetListPushMessages", jsonEncode({
    "hash": globals.UserInfo["md5hash"],
    "count": 50,
  }), (answer){
    print("Enter: $answer");
    globals.NotifyList=answer;
    emit(NotifyLoaded(response: answer);
  }, (error){
  });
});
```